# How to keep connection open for all the time in websockets

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-http

Server code :

```
object EchoService {

  def route: Route = path("ws-echo") {
    get {
      handleWebSocketMessages(flow)
    }
  } ~ path("send-client") {
    get {
      sourceQueue.map(q => {
        println(s"Offering message from server")
        q.offer(BinaryMessage(ByteString("ta ta")))
      } )
      complete("Sent from server successfully")
    }
  }

  val (source, sourceQueue) = {
    val p = Promise[SourceQueue[Message]]
    val s = Source.queue[Message](100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).mapMaterializedValue(m => {
      p.trySuccess(m)
      m
    })
    (s, p.future)
  }

  val flow =
    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(Sink.ignore, source)(Keep.right)
}
```

Client Code :

```
object Client extends App {


  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("akka-system")
  implicit val flowMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val config = actorSystem.settings.config
  val interface = config.getString("app.interface")

  val port = config.getInt("app.port")


  // print each incoming strict text message
  val printSink: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
    Sink.foreach {
      case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
        println(message.text)

      case _ => println(s"received unknown message format")
    }

  val (source, sourceQueue) = {
    val p = Promise[SourceQueue[Message]]
    val s = Source.queue[Message](100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).mapMaterializedValue(m => {
      p.trySuccess(m)
      m
    })
    (s, p.future)
  }

  val flow =
    Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(printSink, source)(Keep.right)


  val (upgradeResponse, sourceClosed) =
    Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest("ws://localhost:8080/ws-echo"), flow)

  val connected = upgradeResponse.map { upgrade =>
    // just like a regular http request we can get 404 NotFound,
    // with a response body, that will be available from upgrade.response
    if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols || upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.OK ) {
      Done
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
    }
  }

  connected.onComplete(println)

}
```

when i hit `http://localhost:8080/send-client` i see messages coming to client but after a while if try to send to client again i don't see any messages on client side :s . I also tried `source.concatMat(Source.maybe)(Keep.right)` but no luck :(

**Edit :** I tested with js client, somehow connection/flow closed on server end , is there anyway to prevent this ? and how can i listen to this event while using akka-http websocket client :s

Answer (score 6):

> Hi,
>
> The reason why it does not keep connected is because by default all
>   HTTP connections have idle-timeout on by default to keep the system
>   from leaking connections if clients disappear without any signal.
>
> One way to overcome this limitation (and actually my recommended
>   approach) is to inject keep-alive messages on the client side
>   (messages that the server otherwise ignore, but informs the underlying
>   HTTP server that the connection is still live).
>
> You can override the idle-timeouts in the HTTP server configuration to
>   a larger value but I don't recommend that.
>
> If you are using stream based clients, injecting heartbeats when
>   necessary is as simple as calling `keepAlive` and providing it a time
>   interval and a factory for the message you want to inject:
>   http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.7/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow@keepAliveU>:Out:FlowOps.this.Repr[U]
>
> That combinator will make sure that no periods more than T will be
>   silent as it will inject elements to keep this contract if necessary
>   (and will not inject anything if there is enough background traffic)
>
> -Endre

thank you Endre :) , working snippet ..

```
// on client side 

 val (source, sourceQueue) = {
    val p = Promise[SourceQueue[Message]]
    val s = Source.queue[Message](Int.MaxValue, OverflowStrategy.backpressure).mapMaterializedValue(m => {
      p.trySuccess(m)
      m
    }).keepAlive(FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), () => TextMessage.Strict("Heart Beat"))
    (s, p.future)
  }
```